# 'Search results for ' text not coming

Tags: magento2

Why is my keyword not displaying  Search results for: 'searched keyword'
 after overriding CatalogSearch module

My Result.php

```
<?php
 namespace Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block;
 use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;
 use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection;
 use Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
 use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList;

class Result extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result
{
    //my custom methods  
}
```

**I dont get this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add protected function _prepareLayout() in my overridden class... Working!!